# Hilbert's Hotel

Tags: ho.history-overview, mathematics-education, infinite-combinatorics

Hilbert's Hotel is a famous story about infinity attributed to David Hilbert (1862-1943).

Is it documented that Hilbert's Hotel is in fact due to Hilbert, and if yes, where?

Comment: http://arxiv.org/abs/1403.0059

Comment: This could have been asked on Math.SE

Answer (score 50):

[The True (?) Story of Hilbert's Infinite Hotel](https://arxiv.org/abs/1403.0059), by Helge Kragh (2014)

> What is known as "Hilbert's hotel" is a story of an imaginary hotel
> with infinitely many rooms that illustrates the bizarre consequences
> of assuming an actual infinity of objects or events. Since the 1970s
> it has been used in a variety of arguments, some of them relating to
> cosmology and others to philosophy and theology. For a long time it
> has remained unknown whether David Hilbert actually proposed the
> thought experiment named after him, or whether it was merely a piece
> of mathematical folklore. It turns out that Hilbert introduced his
> hotel in a lecture of January 1924, but without publishing it. The
> counter-intuitive hotel only became better known in 1947, when George
> Gamow described it in a book, and it took nearly three more decades
> until it attracted wide interest in scientific, philosophical, and
> theological contexts. The paper outlines the origin and early history
> of Hilbert's hotel paradox. At the same time it retracts the author's
> earlier conclusion that the paradox was originally due to Gamow.

*The relevant quote from Hilbert's 1924 [lecture](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/3540205780) is as follows (my translation from German):*

> An application of this fact is provided by the hotel manager, who has
> a hotel with a finite number of rooms. All these rooms are occupied by
> guests. When the guests exchange their room in any way, so that again
> no room has more than one guest, then that will not free a room, and
> the hotel manager cannot in this way make space for a newly arrived
> guest. We can also say: A part of a finite quantity is never equal in
> number to the whole. [...]
>
> How is this for an infinite quantity? Let us take as the simplest
> example the quantity of integer numbers. Here already this law "a part
> is smaller than the whole" no longer holds. We can explain this
> important fact easily using our example of the occupied hotel. This
> time we assume that the hotel has infinitely many numbered rooms,
> $1,2,3,4,5,\ldots$, in each of which there lives a guest. When a new guest
> arrives, all the manager has to do is to allow each of the old guests
> to occupy the room having one number higher, and this will free room
> number 1 for the new arrival. Of course, in this way space can be made
> for any finite number of new guests, and in this world of an infinite
> number of houses and occupants there will be no housing shortage. [...]
>
> Indeed, it is even possible to make space for an infinite number of new guests.
> For example, each of the old guests, originally occupying room number $n$,
> just has to move to number $2n$. Then the infinite number of rooms with
> odd numbers become free for new guests.